# Joint distribution from two gamma distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with distributions $\Gamma(a,c)$ and $\Gamma(b,c)$ respectively. $a,b,c>0$. Set $S=X+Y$ and $T=\frac{X}{X+Y}$. What is the law of the couple $(S,T)$?

I have what should be at least a partial answer, but there are various things I don't understand, so explanations or references that clarify these would be helpful.

We have
$$ f_X(x)=\frac{c^a x^{a-1}e^{-cx}}{\Gamma(a)} \text{ and } 
  f_Y(x)=\frac{c^b x^{b-1}e^{-cx}}{\Gamma(b)} $$
Now we let $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded. (What is this for?)
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} [h(S,T)]  & = \mathbb{E} \left[h \left(X+Y, \frac{X}{X+Y} \right)\right] \\[10pt]
& = \iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^*}  h(x+y,\frac{x}{x+y}) \frac{c^{a+b}}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} x^{a-1}y^{b-1}e^{-cx-cy} \,dx\,dy
\end{align}

Then I have an aside as follows: $\phi:\mathbb{R}_+^*\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+^*\times]0,1[ ,\quad \phi^{-1}(u,v)\mapsto (uv,u(1-v)$ with the comment $uv=x$ and then

$$(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)=(x+y,\frac{x}{x+y})\qquad u=x+y, v=\frac{x}{x+y}$$
Then we do a Jacobean and find a non-zero determinant.

$$ |J_{\phi^{-1}}|= \begin{vmatrix} v & u \\ 1-v & -u \end{vmatrix} = |u|$$ Again I am not sure of the point of the Jacobean, or why the substitutions were made. The next line continues from the integral:

$$
\underset{\mathbb{R}_+^* \times ]0,1[ }{\iint} h(u,v) \frac{c^{a+b}}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}
(uv)^{a-1}(u(1-v))^{b-1}e^{-cu}u\; du\,dv
$$

We then factorise this as follows:
$$
\underset{\mathbb{R}_+^* \times ]0,1[ }{\iint} h(u,v) \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}
(((c^{a+b}u^{a+b-1}e^{-cu})))\quad[[[v^{a-1}(1-v)^{b-1}]]]\;du\,dv
$$
I think this means as the functions of $(((u)))$ and of $[[[v]]]$ contain no terms in $v$ and $u$ we can say that $S$ and $T$ are independent, and we have $S\sim\Gamma(c,a+b)$ and $T\in]0,1[,\;T\sim Beta(a,b)$

I guess the final step is just recognising the individual laws.

What is the purpose of using the function $h$ above? It seems to be standard to then take an expectation of the variables we are interested in.

What is the point of the mapping $\phi$ and the change of variables?  And what does taking the determinant of the Jacobean prove? Explanations or references to an English language source would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**
My question was really about the process of solving the problem above, and I have now found some notes which have clarified what is going on :
http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/Transformations.pdf
See the answer and comments for insightful comments about this particular example.

Comment: You seem to be following some notes or some book, what are they?

Comment: Rather than writing $\displaystyle \underset{\mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^*}{\int\int} $, you can write $\displaystyle \iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^*}$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ Did The example was one we went over in the course (I am not aware of it being in a book), as above, but I am revising fro the retake and seem to have forgotten some of the reasons for the various steps.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy - Thanks

Comment: I am a bit more inclined to approach this first by using ideas from probability and save integrals and Jacobians for later.  I'm trying to remember how I did this last time I saw this problem here${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ were known, or in more mathematical terms, if we consider a family of distributions indexed by $c$ with $a$ and $b$ fixed, then $T$ would be an ancillary statistic, i.e. a statistic whose distribution is the same for all values of $c$, and $S$ would be a complete sufficient statistic; "sufficient" means the conditional distribution of $(X,Y)$ given $S=X+Y$ does not depend on $c$; "complete" means no nonzero function $g$ exists for which $\operatorname{E}(g(S))=0$ regardless of the value of $c$.  (The function $g$ must be the same for all values of $c$.) Therefore$\,\ldots\ \ {}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$by Basu's theorem $S$ and $T$ are independent.  HOWEVER, one would prefer to use more elementary methods.  If you know they're independent and can find their marginal distributions, then you've got it.

Comment: PS: When I refer to a "statistic" I mean something depending on the parameters and the data only through the data; thus a random variable like $cX$ is not a _statistic_. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

To motivate this, suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.  Then we can realize $X$ and $Y$ as waiting times for the first $a$ occurrences and the next $b$ occurrences of a Poisson process with rate $c$ (i.e. if $N(t)$ is the number of occurrences of the Poisson process up to time $t$, $X = \inf \{t: N(t) = a\}$ and $Y = \inf\{t: N(t) = a+b\} - X$.  Then $S$ is the waiting time for the first $a+b$ occurrences of the Poisson process, and $T$ is the fraction of this waiting time that is required for the first $a$ occurrences.
The key point is that given $S=s$, you can consider the first $a+b-1$ occurrence times (unsorted) as a sample of size $a+b-1$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,s]$.