# Under what condition the following variables can be independent? Basic independence query.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

one random variable is defined as $$\gamma_1=\frac{C|h_{sr}|^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_ir}|^2}$$
where $|h_{sr}|$ and all $|h_{P_ir}|$ are independent exponential random variables and $C$ and $D$ are constants. The other random variable is defined as $$\gamma_2=\frac{\min \left[kC|h_{sr}|^2+\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_ir}|^2,F\right]|h_{rd}|^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_id}|^2}$$ where $E,k,F$ are constants and $|h_{sr}|^2,|h_{P_ir}|^2,|h_{P_id}|^2, |h_{rd}|^2$ are independent random variables. Is it possible that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are independent?

My Attempt:

In my view both $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ depend on $h_{sr}$ therefore they can not be independent. But in one of the paper (http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kalamkar/links/Globecom_interference.pdf Title: Interference-Assisted Wireless Energy Harvesting in Cognitive Relay Network with Multiple Primary Transceivers, Read the line above Eq (16) and see Eq (9), Eq (10), Eq (13) and Eq (14) ) it is said that these two variables are independent. Is there something very critical that I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> In my view both $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ depend on $h_{sr}$ therefore they can not be independent.

That's not a valid argument. Two quantities can both depend on a third quantity (among others), yet be mutually independent:

**Proposition 1.** If $X\sim \text{Gamma}(k_X,\theta_X)$ and $Y\sim \text{Gamma}(k_Y,\theta_Y)$ are independent, then $S=X+Y$ and $R=X/Y$ are independent iff  $\theta_X=\theta_Y$.

(Proof omitted -- it's a straightforward transformation-of-variables calculation with a simple Jacobian.)

**NB**: In my notation, $\text{Exponential}(\theta)= \text{Gamma}(1,\theta)$, and $\text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$ has the probability density function $\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\,\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}[x\ge 0].$

There seems to be a typo in your second equation, which I believe should be 
$$\begin{align}\gamma_2
&=\frac{\min \left[k\left(C|h_{sr}|^2+\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_ir}|^2\right),F\right]|h_{rd}|^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_id}|^2}\\ \\
&=\frac{\min \left[k\left(\color{blue}{X+Y}\right),F\right]|h_{rd}|^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_id}|^2}\\
\end{align}$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are the numerator and denominator, respectively, of $\gamma_1$:
$$\begin{align}\gamma_1 &= \color{blue}{\frac{X}{Y}}\\ \\
X&=C|h_{sr}|^2\\ \\
Y &= \sum_{i=1}^{L}D|h_{P_ir}|^2.
\end{align}$$

In the paper, $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with Exponential and Gamma distributions, respectively. In Appendix B, the author derives the CDF of $X/Y$, but does not mention the independence question that you pose; however, given the assumptions stated in the paper, it's clear that *if* $X/Y$ and $X+Y$ are independent then so are $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. (I don't know whether $\theta_X=\theta_Y$ holds in the paper, or whether it may hold in some approximation.)

Another potential line of argument:  If there is a high probability that $X$ is much smaller than $Y$, then, with high probability, 
$$\frac{X}{Y} \approx  \frac{X}{X+Y} $$
so the following might apply:

**Proposition 2.** If $X\sim \text{Gamma}(k_X,\theta_X)$ and $Y\sim \text{Gamma}(k_Y,\theta_Y)$ are independent, then $S=X+Y$ and $T=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ are independent.

(Again omitting a straightforward proof, but see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1312486/16397).)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. It seems that to fulfill this condition we will have to consider the mean value of a typical $|h_{P_ir}|^2$ and the number of terms $L$ to see whether the condition $\Theta_X=\Theta_Y$ holds or not. If this is true then it means that the statement presented in the paper is not generally true but true only for certain number of terms and specific mean values of $|h_{P_ir}|^2$ that makes the condition $\Theta_X=\Theta_Y$. Please comment on this observation. Thank you

Comment: @FrankMoses - As far as I can tell, under the assumptions stated in the paper, $\theta_X=\theta_Y$ is necessary and sufficient for the independence in question.  In the author's notation, this condition is $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$, where $\lambda_x=P_{Sm}\lambda_{sr}$ and $\lambda_y=P_{PT}\lambda_{pr}$. (The condition does not involve the Gamma shape parameter $L$).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me regarding the number of terms. But the problem stays same because in the paper (in my observation) no such condition is discussed that $\lambda_x=\lambda_y=P_{Sm}\lambda_{sr}=P_{PT}\lambda_{pr}$. Because general values of $P_{PT}$, $P_{sm}$, $\lambda_{sr}$ and $\lambda_{pr}$ are considered in the system model of the paper. Further, in appendix B the author write $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$ but they did not clarify that both of them are equal to each other (because then Eq (24) may have been in a relatively simple form by using $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$).